# Invocation of nehek and swarms?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

How does invocation of nehek affect swarms?

For example the bat swarm.

If I cast nehek on a bat swarm that has 4 bases/models with full wounds and nehek replenishes 3 wounds, what happens? Does it create a new base/model with 3 wounds?

If the unit was not a swarm but had multiple wounds for each base, how would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invocation of Nehek (Vampire Counts 8th Ed, pg 60) says that *"Wounds gained are distributed as described in Ressurecting Fallen Warriors"*.

The rules for Ressurecting Fallen Warriors (Vampire Counts 8th Ed, pg 26) state that *"A unit cannot be taken beyond it's starting size, though certain powers, spells and special rules may provide exceptions"*.

So the unit will not go above it's starting size unless the unit or the caster has a special rule saying they may do so (Swarms do not).

The rules for Ressurecting Fallen Warriors go on to say:

*"In the case of multiple Wound models, all models in the unit must be fully healed before another can be resurrected."*

However, Invocation of Nehek does add that *"models with the Vampiric, Ethereal or Large Target special rules can never regain more than 1 Wound per successful casting."*

Comment: Ok, but what if all my models are at full wounds and i heal 3 wounds on a 5 wounds model? Does that new model come into play with 3 wounds or do i have to heal 5 wounds for a new model to show up?

Comment: Assuming that the unit is below it's starting size (or the Vampire has Summon Creatures of the Night etc.)? Yes, a new model will be created with 3 wounds.